# How to stop the if statement from executing further

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code and trying to implement a bad word filtering system but the break is not executing. I thought that break means to stop executing further if statements but it is still progressing through to adding the information to the database..

```
 for (int i = 0; i < badWords.size(); i++) {
                            String badWord = badWords.get(i);
                            if (txt_name.toLowerCase().contains(badWord) || txt_address.toLowerCase().contains(badWord) || txt_suburb.toLowerCase().contains(badWord) || txt_state.toLowerCase().contains(badWord) || postcode2.toLowerCase().contains(badWord) || txt_doctor.toLowerCase().contains(badWord)) {
                                //     txt_review = txt_review.replace(badWord, "*****");
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Make sure that it does not contain any rude words", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            } else if (clinic_name.equals(txt_name) || clinic_name2.equals(txt_name)) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Medical Clinic already exists in the database!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            } else if (txt_name.isEmpty() || txt_address.isEmpty() || phone.isEmpty() || txt_suburb.isEmpty() || txt_state.isEmpty() || postcode2.isEmpty() || txt_doctor.isEmpty()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Make sure you have completed all fields and also make sure they are bulk billing clinics!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                            } else {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run this code in a function and use `return` instead of `break`.

Comment: thanks.... So, how would you know when to use return or break? Or is this merely just a try and error thing